# compass sprite image generated on /tmp

Tags: symfony, sass, sprite, compass-sass

We're using Compass 0.12.2 + Sass 3.2.5 on our Symfony 2.0.10 project. In our `config.yml`, we have indicated the `http_images_path` and the background images are working fine, but we have a problem with the sprite generation, I've tried with the vars:

```
images_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../web/bundles
```

Now, I get the sprite image generated on the `/tmp` folder (`images_dir` is an absolute route, I've tried the same with `image_path` that seems more suitable but it doesn't work)

- **images_path**
- **generated_images_dir**
- **generated_images_path**
- **sprite_load_path**

It didn't work with any of the last four or any combination. On generation I get the error *"image not found on /tmp/images"*.

I have tried to modify `project_path` to `%kernel.root_dir%` and `relative_assets` to `true`, but it doesn't work either.

**In short**: The generated image stays in `/tmp` instead of getting copied into the bundle directory.
How can I get the image sprite generated in the same folder where it's getting the original icons from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have end up making our own sprite.png and embed as base64 image through less on our css, is not a solution for the problem but it's an acceptable workaround for the company.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

(in app/conifg/config.yml)

```
assetic:
filters:
    compass:
        bin: /usr/bin/compass
        apply_to: \.scss$
        http_path: /
        images_dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/images"
        generated_images_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web/images/generated"
        http_generated_images_path: "../web/images/generated"
```

Im saving my images into /web/images
Placing icons for generate the sprites on /web/images/icons
And the resulting sprites on /web/images/generated

Hope it helps !

Comment: yes I have tried this one, Thank you. Anyway we have end up making our own sprite.png and embed as base64 image throigh less on our css.